# ToDo App in C++ with string vector (Give the user the option to delete an entry based on index number)

Tags: c++, stdvector

Successfully created a string vector for storing the entries. A while loop asks for ToDo Items and a SHOW key shows the user all items currently stored in the string vector. For easier access to the items I have an int just displays "running" numbers in fron the items.

After user has added few items he can type DEL what brings him to the deletion mode:
(Here I like to enter 2 what will delete Stop Smoking and rearrange the array to fill
the gap)

[image]

Now I like to get the number the user enteres, decrement with 1 to match to the 
vector array index number and delete the entry but whats the best approach to do this?

This is how I get the items added to the string vector:

```
int taskNumber = 1;
cout<<"New task: ";
getline (cin,newTaskEntry);
taskVector.push_back(newTaskEntry);

cout<<"TOTAL TASKS IN YOUR INBOX: "<<taskVector.size()<<endl;
```

This is how I show the user all entries:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator i = taskVector.begin(); i != taskVector.end(); ++i) 
            {
                cout<<taskNumber<<"  ";
                cout<<*i<<endl;
                taskNumber = taskNumber +1; 
            }
```

Comment: Next time you should really try to isolate your problem from the bigger picture: it was really necessary to explain us what your TODO app does (even with a screenshot!) when your problem really is a "how do I erase the `n`-th entry of a vector"? (ten words!)

Comment: OK, will keep in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do just:

```
cin >> number;
if(number > 0 && number < taskVector.size())
{
    vector<string>::iterator it(taskVector.begin() + number - 1);
    taskVector.erase(it);
}
else
    cout << "Error. Out of bounds\n";
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate to get the correct iterator. `vector::iterator` supports random access.

Comment: Right, your answer is simpler

Answer (score 2):

Use vector's [erase()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) member function. It takes an iterator, but since vectors support random access iterators, that's a non-issue:

```
taskVector.erase(taskVector.begin() + n - 1);  // where n is the number user enters
```

Make also sure `n` isn't bigger than the size of vector.